# Road standards in Morocco?

Tags: road-trips, morocco

I'm planning a casual roadtrip through Morocco with a small car. I notice there are three "ranks" of roads in google maps:

- Blue A-X
- Red N-X
- Yellow R-X
- Yellow P-X

What should i expect on each rank? The things I'm interested in in particular are:

- availability of gas stations
- quality of the road (can I use it driving a, say, fiat 500?)
- what's the speed limit
- what's the actual average speed you can manage

I wanted to check these things using google street view (that's how I planned most of my trips) but apparently, they didn't make it to Morocco.

Comment: Morocco is quite a big country with a lot of roads. Could you restrict the question to a particular route?

Comment: @JonathanReez I think the question is really about what those Road Ranks mean, which sounds to me like a fine question.